# Tangent plane to a surface in $3$-space where gradient is $0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was reading section of tangent planes to surfaces from the book of Several Variable Calculus by Lang; I did not understand one hypothesis.

Suppose a surface in $3$-space is defined implicitly by equation $f(x,y,z)=k$, which is differentiable at a point $(a,b,c)$, **and the gradient of $f$ (i.e. $\nabla f)$ at $(a,b,c)$ is $\neq 0$.** Then tangent plane to the surface at $(a,b,c)$ is the plane passing through $(a,b,c)$ which is perpendicular to $\nabla f(a,b,c)$.

Now, suppose that the gradient of $f$ at $(a,b,c)$ is $0$, then does it imply that we can not define tangent to the surface at such point?

For example, in $2$-variable case, consider the curve defined by $x^2=y^3$. Then with $f(x,y)=x^2-y^3$, the curve is level curve of $f(x,y)=0$. Since $(\nabla f)(0,0)=(f_x,f_y)_0=(0,0)$; but the graph of the curve in $XY$ plane is like gamma curve; and at $(0,0)$, we can draw vertical tangent to it.